# Error when adding foreign key of type string in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I have two tables, a voucher and an order. The voucher needs to have a 16 character string as the ID, which is created randomly. Everything worked when the ID was incremented as an integer, but when changing to string, I just can't get it to add the foreign key, getting this error:

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
 : alter table `orders` add constraint `orders_voucher_id_foreign` foreign k
 ey (`voucher_id`) references `vouchers` (`id`))

 [PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

And here are my tables:

```
    Schema::create('vouchers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->string('id');
        $table->integer('value');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('event_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('voucher_id');
        $table->timestamps();      

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('event_id')->references('id')->on('events');
        $table->foreign('voucher_id')->references('id')->on('vouchers');
    });
```

Any feedback would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these schemas in the same file or different files?

Answer (score 7):

try with:

$table->string('id')->unique();

Comment: Worked first time, you saint xox

Comment: np, glad it helped